# How to register entry and exit time

Tags: c#, sql

There are two tables.
The first table registering personal information, save time entering and exiting the second table

The first table fields: `ID, National code, name`

The second table fields: `ID, National code, entering time, exiting time`. National code foreign key.

When a user enters their national code. Log the time, when for the second time to enter the national code, exiting time record.
But the problem is when a user enters and exit several times during a day, the other just does not work.

I use the following code:

```
if (txt_code.Text != "")
{
    SqlCommand cmdceck = new SqlCommand("select * from tb where code ='" + txt_code.Text + "' ", con);
    SqlDataReader dr;

    con.Open();
    dr = cmdceck.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        p.id= dr["id"].ToString();
        p.code = dr["code"].ToString();
        p.date_enter = dr["date_enter"].ToString();
        p.date_exit = dr["date_exit"].ToString();
    }

    con.Close();

    //
    if (p.date_enter == "" && p.date_exit == "" )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tb set date_enter=@date_enter WHERE code='" + txt_code.Text + "'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("date_enter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lb_date_time.Text;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        fill();
    }
    //
    else if (p.date_enter != "" && p.date_exit == "" )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  tb set date_exit=@date_exit  WHERE code='" + txt_code.Text + "'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("date_exit", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lb_date_time.Text;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        fill();
    }
    //
    else if (p.date_enter != "" && p.date_exit != "" )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into  tb  (code,date_enter) values (@code,@date_enter) ", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_code.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("date_enter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lb_date_time.Text;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        fill();
    }
```

Comment: Dont `UPDATE`! use separate tables for enrty and exit, and perform `INSERT`s only! The biggest part of the problem currently is in you updates, and apparently there is no other way to fix them except getting rid of them.

Comment: Please see program:   http://s7.picofile.com/d/b5f050f7-5c7b-4fb5-b4bd-5c2c1ee296aa/WindowsFormsApplication2.zip

Comment: No. Ask here, not on picofile.com.

Comment: I'm sorry, please download the uploaded file and run the program yourself